# Post types - Normal Post - Image

Tags: post-type

I use the ios app to administer [my blog](http://www.siphilp.co.uk). On occasion I also post life pictures up.  Question is that when I post an image up from my iPhone the type (image) is shown in the list of post titles.

I can't see where this is set? When I go into edit the above post or even create a new post. Is this down to the current theme I am using or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress iOS app tends to favour setting a default post format value depending on the content. What you are seeing is called a Post Format, you can read all about them [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). It sounds to me like you're using a default Wordpress theme or a theme that uses post formats.

The default TwentyEleven Wordpress theme uses post formats, so you'll find if you're using it the offending code will be in the root directory of the theme and be called content-image.php, this file only gets called if a post is assigned to the post format value of image.

I presume you're using the "Quick Photo" option in the app? [This update page](http://ios.wordpress.org/category/update-2/) for the app shows that using "Quick Photo" will use a post format of image if your theme supports it. Is the issue here that image is being added to blog titles, or you can see the type images showing up in your posts lists but from a front-end perspective the titles are fine?

## **Updated answer based on response**

In your theme `function.php` file add the following line:

```
add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio'));
```

Then once you edit a post you'll notice a post formats box on the right hand side and if it's post formats that are causing the addition of image to your posts, then you should see the offending post has a post format of image.

Comment: I'd just like to see if there is an option to change the format through the admin ui. Reason for question is i'd like to assign "image" to some posts through WLW/Admin.... :S

Comment: Other definitely. I'll update my answer to reflect accordingly.

Comment: No worries and by the way, welcome to the site! This page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) on the Wordpress Codex has some great information about Post Formats, for things like checking in your templates if a post has a certain post format and changing how it is displayed.